# Adding a nvd3 sparkline chart inside a dynamic table

Tags: jquery, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

I create a table on-the-fly based on a server response. Within this table cell, I'm adding a sparkline chart.

I'm not able to make this chart fit the cell. I've pasted the snippet below.

```
function populateTop5Table(top5Obj) {
    var tempTable = jQuery("<table />");

    var tableBody = jQuery("<tbody />")
    jQuery.each(top5Obj, function() {
    jQuery("<tr />")
      .append(
        jQuery("<td />", {
          html : this.current
        })
      )
      .append(
        jQuery("<td />")
        .append(
          jQuery("<div />", {
            "id": "sparkline" + this.id,
            "height": "30px",
            //"width": "200px"
          }
          // Trend Sparkline chart
          ).each(function() {
            loadSparklineChart(this, someParameterRelatedToThisRow)
          })
        )
      ).appendTo(tableBody);
    });

    tableBody.appendTo(tempTable);

    $("#top5Table").empty();
    $("#top5Table").append(tempTable);
}

function loadSparklineChart(chartDiv, someParameterRelatedToThisRow) {
    var sparkChart = nv.models.sparkline()
          // .width(200)
          .height(30)
    var maindiv = d3.select(chartDiv)

    var sparkChartSvg = maindiv.append("svg").attr("height", "30px");

    // for now adding sine series, which I'll later replace by another 
    // ajax call to get chart value, based on someParameterRelatedToThisRow.
    sparkChartSvg.datum(sine())
        .call(sparkChart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(sparkChart.update);
}
```

Since, I'm adding the chart to the cell, even before it is added to the document. div's initial size is 0x0 which after adding to the document gets adjusted, however chart doesn't gets resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. this time, I'm postponing loadSparklineChart call until it is added to the document. As below:

```
...
.append(
  jQuery("<td />")
  .append(
    jQuery("<div />", {
      "id": "sparkline" + this.id,
      "height": "25px",
      "class": "sparlineClass",
      "someParameterRelatedToThisRow" : "value"
    })
  )
)
...

$("#top5Table").empty();
$("#top5Table").append(tempTable);

// Trend Sparkline chart
$("#top5Table .sparlineClass").each(function() {
  loadSparklineChart(this, this.getAttribute("someParameterRelatedToThisRow"))
})
```

and in the loadSparklineChart

```
function loadSparklineChart(chartDiv, someParameterRelatedToThisRow) {
  var divWidth = $(chartDiv).width();
  var sparkChart = nv.models.sparkline()
              .width(divWidth)
              .height(25);

  var maindiv = d3.select(chartDiv);

  var sparkChartSvg = maindiv.append("svg").attr("height", "25px");

  sparkChartSvg.datum(sine())
    .call(sparkChart);

  // I've to call this
  $(chartDiv).parent().width(divWidth);

  nv.utils.windowResize(sparkChart.update);
}
```

with this I'm able to solve the issue.

Hope this helps someone.